# I am trying to seed data into a database, and I keep getting an error that states "String or binary will be truncated"?

Tags: c#, database

I have checked all the lengths of the object's values, and I know it's not that. I have two classes' data that I'm entering(Foods and Customers), and I am using one `EnsureSeedDataForContext` to enter both, and at the end I add both to a database  (`GoDeliveryContext` is the class used to create the database)

e.g.

```
public static void EnsureSeedDataForContext(this GoDeliveryContext context)
    {     
      var customers = new List<Customer>
        {

            new Customer()
            {
                //CustomerId is created by database
                Name = "Henno",
                Adress = "12 Le Roux Street, Maryland",
                MobileNr = "0876277898",
                CreatedAtDate = new DateTime(2011, 02, 12),
                UpdatedAtDate = new DateTime(2016, 12, 11)
            }
        }  
 var foods = new List<Food>()
        {

            new Food()
            {
              //  FoodId created by the database.
                Name = "Big Mac",
                Description = "The original Big Mac Hamburger",
                Cost = 32,
                RestaurantId = 2,
                CreatedAtDate = new DateTime(2012, 04, 12),
                UpdatedAtDate = new DateTime(2017, 02, 11)
            }
        }
} 
  context.Customers.AddRange(customers); 
  context.Foods.AddRange(foods)  ;
```

and after that I save the range

```
    context.SaveChanges();
```

---

```
public class Customer
{

    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string Adress { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(10)]
    public string MobileNr { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime CreatedAtDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime UpdatedAtDate { get; set; }


}

public class Food
{

    [Required]
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int FoodId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string Name { get; set; }


    [Required]
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public float Cost { get; set;}

    [Required]
    public int RestaurantId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime CreatedAtDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime UpdatedAtDate { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: check column lengths.. it seems one of the column value exceed the db column length.

Comment: "and i know it's not that"... then it is. Could you show the schema/ddl of the `Customer` and `Food` tables as they actually appear in the database you're connected to? before looking into more obscure things like triggers. from the error message I take that this is a Microsoft SQL Server?

Comment: @mukeshkudi I have checked the column lengths and I will check it again

Comment: @dlatikay Yes it is Microsoft SQL Server. And are you asking for the classes(Customer and Food), or the database information?

Comment: the table schema of the database your code is actually connecting to at runtime: column name, column data type with column length, any computed columns/computed defaults/triggers?

Comment: No computed/triggers?

Comment: @dlatikay is that what you wanted?

Comment: @Henk Can you please try the Date Time Input in MM-dd-yyyy format?

Comment: Do you have other customers you have not shown us? Do any of them have mobile numbers greater than 10 chars?

Comment: year, month, day is the correct order of arguments for the `DateTime` constructor. @Henk what I meant was to compare your "code first" table definition class with what actually ended up in your SQL database. use SQL Studio or the tools integrated in VS to look at the table design and compare lengths. Maybe you lost a migration since you used smaller column lengths before?

Comment: Can you confirm if the data type for the date in the DB is datetime or date?

Comment: When I do a `"0876277898".Length` it returns `10`; however if I use SA's dialing code `"+27876277898".Length` it's larger than 10. That's not even including SA's International call prefix.

Comment: @MartinSmith i have tested all the other customer's numbers, none longer than 10.

Comment: @AkbarBadhusha it does not work, however the database's length of datetime is 7, so i think that is the problem

Comment: @Barnstokkr i am only entering 0.... format, as the api is just a local company exercise. Also from sa though

Answer (score 0):

Okay, i found the problem. For some reason the DateTime gets changed to

> DateTime2(7)

when i migrate to the database, which causes an error with the entered date. The solution for this is to write the specific date, time and DateTimeKind, e.g.

> CreatedAtDate = new DateTime(2018,12,12,10,10,12,DateTimeKind.Local)

Thank you for the help! Hope this helps anyone else that might be having this issue.